# Revolution Slider JS Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rev Slider conflicting with default jQuery source.

If I remove the following, the Rev Slider works but obviously I loose all js features!

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://localhost:8888/AGA/wp-content/themes/stop-illegal-gambling/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Console Log:**

> Failure at Loading:revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js on
>   Path://localhost:8888/AGA/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/
>   jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:14918
>
> Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:
>   .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders:
>   .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader:
>   .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:
>   .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort:
>   .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always:
>   .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }
>   jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:15006 Slider Revolution 5.0
>   Error ! jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:14872 Failure at
>   Loading:revolution.extension.navigation.min.js on
>   Path://localhost:8888/AGA/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/
>   jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:14918
>
> Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:
>   .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders:
>   .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader:
>   .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:
>   .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort:
>   .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always:
>   .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az72L.png)

Any help and advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067539/slider-revolution-5-0-error/42780604#42780604]

Answer (score 0):

The Same error was in this site reported and the error due to port used (port 8888). Try to change it to 80.

http://forum.muffingroup.com/betheme/discussion/10127/revolution-slider-not-working-failing-to-load-resources