# Wordpress: facing Javascript error with Slider revolution 5.0

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress template in LAMP, and I am using revolution slider for sliders, I've created the slider and embedded it to the home page. When I view the home page the slider is not playing and I get the following error in the console.

> "Slider Revolution 5.0 Error
>   !jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:16730 Failure at
>   Loading:revolution.extension.video.min.js on
>   Path://localhost/education/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:16776
>
> Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:
>   .ajax/w.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders:
>   .ajax/w.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader:
>   .ajax/w.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:
>   .ajax/w.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/w.statusCode(), abort:
>   .ajax/w.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always:
>   .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }"

Comment: Try disabling your plugins one by one and see if the problem goes away...

Comment: I just have slider revolution and woocommerce plugin activated, and no other plugins are active.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of errors appear when some conflicts arises between JavaScript libraries such as jquery. To solve this you have to use compatibility mode while using jQuery. This compatibility mode can be achieved by using **"jQuery"** instead of **"$"** (That is, replace all occurrences of **"$"** with **"jQuery"**). Here is an example of how you can use it,

```
    /* Normal jQuery you see everywhere */
    $("#some-element").someFunction();

    /* "Safe" jQuery you see in WordPress */
    jQuery("#some-element").someFunction();
```

For more information you may refer [this](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/) link.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your version of Revolution Slider. It worked for me.